# Proof that the equation $x^2=\sin x $ has only one real solution different than $0$

Tags: calculus

I started doing it as following:

Let $f(x) = \sin x - x^2$

Using the fact that $\sin x> x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$, I got that $f(\frac{1}{2})>0$ and, as $0<\sin 1< 1 , f(1)<0$. So, as consequence of Rolle's theorem, there is *at least one* $c \in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$. Moreover, $f'(x) = \cos x - 2x$, then $f'(x)<0$ for every $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$, which guarantees that this c is unique.

Could someone help me to prove that there are no other solutions apart from $0$ on $(-\infty,\frac{1}{2})$?

Other proof suggestions would be also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f''(x)=-\sin x-2\le-1$, $f'$ is always decreasing and hence can be zero at most once. As you noted, $f'(x)<0$ if $x>\frac12$. Also note that $f'(0)=1>0$. Hence $f'(x)=0$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $f$ has at most one turning point and hence at most two zeroes. Since you have already found two, these must be all of them.